# Is there a way to control the FPS in Pygame Zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pygame

I'm working on a simple project using pygame zero and so far I've been able to display a group of images to form a very simple animation. I rendered the video out into a .png sequence at 60 fps. It seems like pygame zero is rendering them out a bit faster than that and I was just wondering if there was a way to lock the FPS to 60 so everything would render as I'd expect it to. I have some sound files that I'd like to sync up with the image sequence, so having them render at a constant FPS would be very helpful.

I've also noticed that the sound keeps looping after it's played, so I tried to stop it after it's played, but the sound cuts off at the end because the animation seems to be finishing too early.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import pgzrun

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 360

# boot1 graphics
boot1 = Actor('boot1_1')
boot1.frame = 1
boot1.active = True

# boot2 graphics
boot2 = Actor('boot2_1')
boot2.frame = 1
boot2.active = False

# overlay
overlay = Actor("overlay_a")


def update_boot1():
    if boot1.active:
        boot1.x = WIDTH/2 
        boot1.image = "boot1_{}".format(boot1.frame)
        boot1.frame += 1
    else:
        boot1.x = 1000
    if boot1.frame > 59:
        #boot1.frame = 1
        boot2.active = True
        update_boot2()
        boot1.active = False


def update_boot2():
    if boot2.active:
        boot2.x = WIDTH/2 
        sounds.boot1.play()
        boot2.image = "boot2_{}".format(boot2.frame)
        boot2.frame += 1
    else:
        boot2.x = 1000
    if boot2.frame > 233:
        boot2.frame = 233
        boot2.active = False
        sounds.boot1.stop()


def draw():
    screen.clear
    screen.fill((0, 75, 0))
    boot2.draw()
    boot1.draw()
    overlay.draw()

# running the animation
def update(dt):
    update_boot1()
    update_boot2()

pgzrun.go()
```

I also haven't found a way to "unload" the image sequences, or make them not visible when I'm done with them, so I just throw them off to the side with ".x = 1000".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but I have found an answer.
If you are to go to your-python-folder/site-packages/pgzero/game.py and edit line 235. It should be "dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000.0" where 60 is the fps.

I have tested it on a chromebook (lame i know) with python 3.9.1 and this does in fact change the frame rate, it even takes decimals.

Hope this helps you or anyone who needs this.

Answer (score -1):

in your running loop, just use:
    just use clock.tick(60)#or whatever fps you want

Comment: So I should put "clock.tick(60)" in the "def update()" loop?

Comment: do you have a while loop that will infinitly loop through it's self?

Comment: No, I'm using pygame zero, not regular pygame. So I believe it works a bit differently. But I noticed that when I run the code through IDLE instead of Visual Studio Code, it seems to run better. So I'm hoping that maybe that was the problem.